# R spreaded matrix but had Error: Can't assign to elements that don't exist

Tags: r, matrix, collaborative-filtering, spread, recommenderlab

Win10 Build 18363.836; R version R-4.0.2; RStudio version 1.3.1093; CPU: Intel i7-7500U; Physical Memory: 16GB; HDD: 500GB SSD

I am working on the [Instacart Market Basket](https://www.kaggle.com/c/instacart-market-basket-analysis/data) dataset. Inorder to build recommendation models with the [recommenderlab](/questions/tagged/recommenderlab) R package, I need to create a matrix with customer_id and product_name for collaboration filtering.

After loaded the data, I merged and filtered the data to prepare the training set.

```
data_train = orders %>% 
  filter(eval_set=='train') %>% 
  left_join(order_products) %>%
  left_join(products) %>%
  mutate(actual=1) %>%
  select(user_id, order_id, product_id, product_name, actual)
```

I tried to build the matrix like this.

```
data_train %>% 
  select(user_id, product_name) %>% 
  mutate(n=1)  %>%
  arrange(product_name) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "product_name", values_from = "n", values_fill=0)
```

But got error message：

> Error Can't assign to elements that don't exist. x
> Locations 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc. don't exist. i There are only 1 element.

I am not able to solve the issue, so I tried another way to build matrix according to this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/market-basket-analysis-with-recommenderlab-5e8bdc0de236)：

```
ratings_matrix <- train01 %>%
  select(user_id, product_name) %>% 
  mutate(value = 1) %>%
  spread(product_name, value, fill = 0) %>%
  select(-user_id) %>%
  as.matrix() %>%
  as("binaryRatingMatrix")
ratings_matrix
```

Now it shows：

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 19.2 Gb

So I extened the memory limition by:

```
memory.limit(50000)
```

Then I checked my system, it shows a total paging file for all drive 43377MB (as virtual memory), which is far more than R asked for generating the matrix. But still got the same error message.

I also tried to split the train data to four pieces, and just converted 25% of it, but still got error:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 3.2 Gb

This is even far less than the available physical memory now on my laptop. And since I need to do the collaborative filtering for the data, it is better to generate the matrix as a whole piece. Can anyone  help me to find out what kind of mistake I made on the coding, or teach me another way to generate the matrix? Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen the function [`realRatingMatrix`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/recommenderlab/versions/0.2-6/topics/realRatingMatrix) which can convert from a dataframe having "user/item/rating triplets as rows"? Seeing that this is essentially the format you have before trying to build your oversized matrix, this might help (it's gutfeel, I don't have experience with the `recommenderlab` package)

Comment: @alex_jwb90: good to know, I will look into the realRatingMatrix to see if it works. Thanks.